Salvia rosmarinus - frost hardiness
I found it can survive -6 °C. But that's not clear, is -6 °C for 2 weeks still fine? Is -2 °C for a week still fine? In both cases, it means 24/7 frost, it's not the same as temporary temperature fall and day temperature above 0.
So far, after 3 day long 24/7 frosts -4 night and -2 day everything is fine, alive and still green, it looks healthy.
Do you have any experience with that?
After 3 days 24/7 frost and one week without frost:

I think it's damaged a bit, some leaves are black, what do you think?

It's hard to give a good answer without more details. Where is the plant located? Can you add a picture? How old is the plant?

Small one, it's first winter. I will add some pictures later

Picture added to question

Around here it's always been popular to use a cut plastic bottle to protect spring saplings, flowers and whatnot. Would have even posted it as an answer had I not fully agreed with Ecnerwal. Lastly, I admire the "experiment" comment!

I'm located in Poland, so in general, my experiment is high risk failure experiment. But this year, so far, the winter is much warmer than normal.

It's not even December yet, and seems likely that you'll have colder weather in January/February; at least that's the way it works anywhere I have experience with that goes below freezing in November. So digging it up and potting it to keep inside for the winter while it's still not dead is likely better than waiting until after it's dead.
Have had good results from digging up and potting rosemary for the winter in zone 4/5 and complete death for any left outside (or in an unheated tunnel) through winter.
If you can't manage/fit the entire plant indoors, take cuttings and root them; just take more cuttings than you expect to need so any that don't root will not be a large impact; if more survive than you've allowed for, give some away.

I have some in the pots also. 2 plants grow in solid ground as an experiment. I'm thinking about making a good cover from leaves and hay. Cover the plant with some kind of container and put thick layer of leaves and hay to it. Covered this way, it won't freeze. Without any light though

Also a tissue on the rosemary may help (but not ideal: it increases plant temperature, but not so much, but tissues with snow may break branches, and so worsening the freezing). -- Also note on OP: being "alive" may be apparent, or just alive, but for few years you will not be able to take good branches.

Picture added to my question
